# blocking certain websites, when accessing through "proxy"

Tags: proxy

My mac at home is controlled by parental control from apple. Internet access is only allowed for certain websites. I did this because i just procrastinate too much.

This works well, but there is a site i have to log in (for work,  guess its extranet), from which i can click through and get to google.com and then the filtering is basically away and i can access every site. i am not very familiar with this but it seems that my worksite works kinda like a proxy.

I want to be able to log into my work-site, and block the access to google, since i am sure its not needed for my worksite to function. Is it possible to block this? Any ideas how? i don't need access to google.com on this account.

Comment: Have you spoken to your work IT department?

Comment: "I did this because i just procrastinate too much." Honestly, this sounds like more procrastination. Instead of wasting time surfing websites you're wasting time trying to lock yourself out of surfing websites. I would just consider your work proxy verboten for frivolous web surfing (since they obviously log/monitor it) and get to work.

Comment: thank you for the fast answer. - i already did contact the IT Departement, but they didnt understand me, since this is an unusual request. I think it will be a stupid idea to ask them again. - procrastination is a problem for my studies, not for the work. I need the access only to make some bookings for work, not for working directly. Actually i have to say its a real problem, kinda like internet addiction. I just can't control it and parental controls have been a big relief for me, for years.
- actually i can't type in "google.com" in the adress bar. I can get to it only by clicking my way th

Answer (score 0):

This "site" that you mention is likely a VPN.  You can think of the VPN as a direct connection through to your workplace.  When you type google.com into your address bar, you are sending a request across the VPN to your workplace, and then out to the general internet.

Since you're parental controls are implemented locally, you are effectively bypassing them.  The only way to block websites on your work's network would be to contact your IT department.  However, I doubt they'll take special action to prevent you from reaching Google.

Answer (score 0):

One idea is to use the host file blocking method if you have local admin access. Example:

> 127.0.0.1 google.com

putting the above line into your host file would redirect your browser traffic to your localhost instead of fetching Google website.

Of course, since this is a local solution and if you can add an entry to the host file, ultimately you can also remove them. But hopefully your will power and the thought of changing the host file repetitively will prevent you from doing that!

The detailed steps to modify the host file for Mac OS X can be found here:
http://pointhope.de/tips&tricks/no_place_like_localhost.html

Comment: This won't even work, see my answer for why.  This is equivalent of what he's already accomplished using Apple Parental Care